# Div Class Text not saving

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to collect prices for films on Vudu. However, when I try to pull data from the relevant div container, it returns as empty.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.vudu.com/content/movies/details/title/835625"
response = get(url)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)
price_container = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'row nr-p-0 nr-mb-10')
```

Result:

```
In [43]: price_container
Out[43]: []
```

As you can see here, the price information is contained in a the div class I specified:

[image]

Comment: It appears that this is one of those sites whose pages are built within the browser using javascript. You should consider using a product such as Selenium for scraping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the page source, the `<body>` contains the following HTML:

```
<div id="loadingScreen">
    <div class="loadingScreenViewport">
        <div class="loadingScreenBody">
            <div id="loadingIconClock">
                <div class="loadingIconBox">
                    <div></div><div></div>
                    <div></div><div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything else are the `<script>` tags (JavaScript). This website is heavily driven by JavaScript. That is, all the other contents are added dynamically.

As you can see, there is no `div` tag with `class="row nr-p-0 nr-mb-10"` in the page source (which is what `requests.get(...)` returns). This is why, `price_container` is an empty list.

You need to use other tools like [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) to scrape this page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip to use Selenium. I was able to get the price information with the following code.

```
browser.get("https://www.vudu.com/content/movies/details/title/835625")

price_element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='row nr-p-0 nr-mb-10']")
prices = [x.text for x in price_element]
```